# Flags - Recreate the 'poke' function

Tags: 7, users, flags, views

I need to create a flags view that displays a list of users that have "poked" the current user with D7, Views 3 and Flag 3. I've read through [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6271/d7-views-flag-view-of-users-flagged-by-a-user-users-flagging-a-user-and) and [drupal.org/node/296971](http://drupal.org/node/296971), neither instruction seems to work or at least I am not able to get the settings right.

To define the functionality:

1. Users are presented with a list view of other users
2. Users click the "poke" flag link on a single user
3. Users then browse to /pokes/ and view all other people that have poked them

This is either a difficult setup or I'm missing a couple settings (the latter is extremely likely). Any hints or thoughts?

Comment: Flag/unflag. Poke/unpoke ?

Comment: Let "poke" == flag for now. I plan to add an unflag action when users view their list of pokes/flags, but that can happen later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created a test site with Flag and Views module enabled and so far, I could create a view to display users who have poked *me*.

Create a new Flag to flag users. This don't have to be a global flag. Flag text could be "Poke" and unflag text could be "remove".

> Users are presented with a list view of other users
>   Users click the "poke" flag link on a single user

1. Create a view on users table
2. Add a new relationship: **Flags: User**.
3. Uncheck "Include only flagged content "; Choose the poke flag; By: Current user. 
   [image]
4. You will see a new field "**Flags: Flag link**". Add it.

You will now get a view that shows users and a flag link to flag them. Modify the View as you wish. 
http://paste2.org/CGZshUFN

> Users then browse to /pokes/ and view all other people that have poked
>   them

This is a really tricky part.

1. Create a new View on users table.
2. Add a new relationship: **Flags: User flag**.
3. Uncheck "Include only flagged content "; Choose the poke flag; By: Any user. 
   [image]
4. Add a new contextual filter: **Flags: Content ID**
5. Under contextual filter settings, choose the just-added relationship and set to user the current logged in user ID. 
   [image]
6. Now we have access to a list of user IDs that has flagged the currently logged in user.
7. Add a new relationship: **Flags: User**
8. Under this relationship's settings, check "require this relationship".
9. Add a new field: **User: name** and choose the relationship created in step #7.
10. Add a new relationship: **Flags: User flag** (yes, you are added one already in step 2 but go ahead).
11. Under this relationship's settings, choose the the user relationship created at step #7. Uncheck "include only flagged content"; By: current user.
    [image]
12. Add a new field: **Flags: Flag link** and choose the relationship created at step #10. 
    http://paste2.org/tkWg99vp

Above step 12 will add the "flag back" type link that the user can see a list of users who have flagged the current user and a link to flag them back. 
You will need many Views template tweaks to adjust the wording of the View to suit your need.

Good luck!

Comment: INCREDIBLE answer, thanks so much for your hard work! This is performing quite well so far. I'm having trouble showing multiple 'pokes', any ideas?
EDIT: Nevermind, had "Distinct" query turned on!

Answer (score 1):

It works for me too. But When multiple people flagged the same user, When I go on its profile and see the numbers of users who flagged him, I always see the first one and not the others.

In my code I count the number of users who flagged him with this script :

```
if ($flag) {
 print "The number of people who voted for this proposal:";
 print $flag->get_count($user->uid);
}
```

And I my output is 3 people.

I don't know why I see only 1 user.