# Views for nodes of Flagged user

Tags: views, flags

i created a User flag call (follow). user can follow eachother.
i want create a views show flagged nodes + user added nodes,like facebook when you login in your facebook profile you can see your Posts and your friends posts.

I found this [View of users flagged by a user, users flagging a user, and nodes from users flagged by a user](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6271/view-of-users-flagged-by-a-user-users-flagging-a-user-and-nodes-from-users-fla)  but ways on that questions just  follower list node.